# How to disable Javascript in IE 6?

Tags: javascript, cookies, internet-explorer-6

How can I completely disable cookies and JavaScript in Internet Explorer 6 (under Windows XP). This is for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to disable Java in Internet Explorer 6:

1. From the **Tools** menu, choose **Internet Options...** .
2. Click the **Security** tab.
3. Click **Custom Level...** .

   - Java: Scroll to the **Java** section (under "Java VM", under "Java permissions"). To disable Java, click **Disable Java** (to re-enable Java, click a different setting, such as High Safety or Medium Safety.)
   - JavaScript: Scroll to the **Active scripting** section of the list (under "Scripting") Click **Disable** (or Enable).
4. Close and restart your browser.

To block cookies in Internet Explorer 6 go to **Tools**, choose **Internet Options...**, select the **Privacy** tab, click the **Advanced** button, clear the box **Override automatic cookie handling** and make your choices.